# HTMLPanel In GWT

Tags: gwt

now according to "http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/tags-first-gwt/"
told that it is recommended to use html&css to build the application user interface and then do the logic using GWT.

i made that UI using html. and added it to HtmlPanl.

now the Question is : 
how to send the htmlPanel content to the server and get the response on the client side ?
i need a simple example that describe this.

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The link that you point to is one year and half old, and that's an eternity in our world ;)

The main point of using pure HTML is to reduce the HTML complexity level when GWT generates it.

I would recommend you to check the documentation about [UIBinder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) and follow the standard ways.